# Count and Max Columns Group By in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have model

```
public class Rate
{
    public int Nr{ get; set; }
    public string Rate{ get; set; }
    public int Order{ get; set; }
}
```

and a `RateList = List<Rate>` like this

```
Nr  |  Rate |  Order
123 |   A   |    2
425 |   A+  |    1
454 |   B   |    4
656 |   B+  |    3
465 |   A   |    2
765 |   B   |    4
```

Notice that Order always match the Rate `(A+ = 1, A = 2, B+ = 3, B = 4, C+ = 5 ...)`
I want to count how many time the Rate occoured and display order by  the Order

The result should look like this

```
  Rate | Count | Order
   A+  |   1   |  1
   A   |   2   |  2
   B+  |   1   |  3
   B   |   2   |  4
```

or without column Order

```
  Rate | Count 
   A+  |   1   
   A   |   2   
   B+  |   1   
   B   |   2
```

In SQL I could do like this if I had above list in table `Tab`

```
SELECT Rate, COUNT(Rate), Max(Order) from Tab group by Rate
```

but in LINQ?

I was trying something like this

```
    var rating= RateList.Distinct().GroupBy(x => x.Rate)
.Select(x => new { Rate = x.Key, RateCount = x.Count() })
.OrderBy(x => x.Order);
```

but didnt work.
Thank You for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query is equevalent to:

```
var rating = rateList.GroupBy(x => x.Rate)
                     .Select(x => new { 
                              Rate = x.Key, 
                              RateCount = x.Count(e => e != null),
                              Max = x.Max(g => g.Order) 
                       });
```

Comment: I added at the end `.OrderBy(x => x.Ordem)` and I get what I wanted, thank You :)